# javascript function not defined even its defined

Tags: javascript

I am trying to call a function on button click and it throws function name not defined. Where I am doing it wrong?

Here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bfz5thj1/1/)

```
function showit(){
var el = document.getElementById("testBox");
alert(el);
}

<input type=text id='testBox'>
<input type=button value='click' onclick='showit()'>
```

Comment: Open the JavaScript settings and change the load type to "no wrap - in body"

Comment: or "in head" And then change to `alert(el.value)`

Comment: interesting no wrap fix. What does this do actually?

Comment: The reason is the wrapping of the function in an onload hides the function from the button